# backbone.js newcomer - error creating collection in app namespace initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm following the the book, Backbone.js on Rails and am creating the basic todo application alongside reading it but I am getting the following javascript error trying to initialize a collection inside the applications namespace:

Error: TodoApp.Collections.Notes is not a constructor
Source File: localhost:3000/assets/todo_app.js?body=1
Line: 13

todo_app.js

```
var TodoApp = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function(data) {
    console.log("INITIALIZE");
    var notes = new TodoApp.Collections.Notes(data.notes); 
    new TodoApp.Routers.Notes({ notes: notes }); 
    Backbone.history.start();    
  }
};
```

I've followed the instructions so far and created a Note model, Notes collection and router and this is how the initialize method is called on index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  TodoApp.initialize({ notes: <%== @notes.to_json %> });
<% end %>
```

This is the order I'm including all of the files:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require json2
//= require backbone
//= require backbone-support
//
//= require todo_app
//
//= require_tree ./models 
//= require_tree ./collections 
//= require_tree ./views 
//= require_tree ./routers 
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .
```

Can anyone help with this? What have I missed out here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TodoApp.initialize({ notes: <%== @notes.to_json %> });` seems like a typo. It should be `TodoApp.initialize({ notes: <%= @notes.to_json %> });` instead.

Comment: thanks for replying.  For reasons I don't understand yet, if I use a single = like you suggest the json gets renderes with &quot; instead of actual quotes

Comment: @user1168320: That's because it is being HTML encoded, you want to add a `raw` or `.html_safe` into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is evaluated in the order it is loaded, so I guess your app is trying to initialize before the files containing the collection is loaded (you're including todo_app before the other files).

Either include todo_app last or listen to the document onload event and initialize the app after the page has been fully loaded.

Comment: Hi ivarni, thanks for the reply.  If I try to load the todo_app last, strangely I get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
TodoApp.initialize({ notes: <%= @notes.to_json.html_safe -%> });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to instantiate the new collection and then fill it up using the `reset` method.

In your example it should be something like this:

```
initialize: function(data){
  var notes = new TodoApp.Collections.Notes()
  notes.reset(data.notes)
```

}

The "reset" method accepts either a list of models or a hash. See the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) for more information.

Another good way to use this method is preloading the information on the webpage and then having our collection filling itself with the stored data. You can insert is on a div using a data tag like this:

```
<%= content_tag "div", "Can be blank", id: "container-id", data: { notes: Notes.all } %>
```

And then call:

```
notes.reset($('#container-id').data 'notes')
```

You can check [Ryan Bates Screencasts on Backbone](http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2?view=asciicast) if you'll like to get more information. Beware that to watch those videos you have to subscribe to his site.

PS: If the location of yout todo_app.js is on your javascript asset folder you don't have to add it using the asset pipeline because it will be automatically picked up by rails by the `//= require_tree .` line.